# Using Tensorflow in Julia 1.0.0

Tags: tensorflow, julia

I successfully added `TensorFlow` with

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("TensorFlow")
```

But when I

```
using TensorFlow
```

I get `Failed to precompile TensorFlow`. In more detail, I get something like below.

```
[ Info: Precompiling TensorFlow 
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: warn not defined 
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
 [2] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [3] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
 [4] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
 [5] top-level scope at none:2
 [6] eval at ./boot.jl:319 [inlined]
 [7] eval(::Expr) at ./client.jl:389
 [8] top-level scope at ./none:3
in expression starting at 
/home/...
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Is there more to that error message, or does it literally cut off at `/home/...`? Normally the next line will contain info about exactly which line is causing the error which is helpful in diagnosing the problem. If you're worried about exposing your username, just replace it with x's in the copy/paste. Also, note that there are quite a few packages that are not updated for v1.0 yet. It will probably be another few weeks before the ecosystem is mostly caught up.

Comment: Here the problem is that `warn` was renamed to `@warn` in 1.0 and probably this was not updated in this package yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit unfortunate, but most packages have not defined any upper bounds on Julia versions (in the past), and thus allow themselves to be installed on Julia 1.0, while they are not ready yet as was pointed out in the comments. If in doubt, I would always check the repository. A quick Google search points to https://github.com/malmaud/TensorFlow.jl.

- The badges at the top of the README show that it only tested for Julia 0.5 & 0.6, indicating it might not be ready (or the author did not add the badge, but it is ready)
- The last release is from May 30th, Julia 0.7 and 1.0 (1.0 = 0.7 minus the deprecation warnings) are just weeks old, so that will definitely not work unless the package is trivial (and this one is not).
- There is plenty of activity to port it to 1.0, particularly in this pull request: https://github.com/malmaud/TensorFlow.jl/pull/419. If you would like to contribute, I would start from that work, it seems a lot has been sorted out, but not all of it